# Как нажать на стандартные кнопки андроида используя Ruby, Appium?

Tags: android, ruby

Привет.
Я пишу автотесты на руби для андроид приложения используя Appium. 
Мне надо нажать на стандартную кнопку назад. но ничего не получается.
Подскажите как это сделать?

Comment: Вопрос не по теме, так как задан не на русском языке.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на ru.SO! Официальный язык этого ресурса - русский. Пожалуйста, переведите Ваш вопрос. Возможно, Вы искали  оригинальное сообщество SO - оно [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com). Welcome to ru.SO! The official language of this resource is Russian. Please, translate your question. If you are looking for the original SO - you could find it [here](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Пожалуйста, обратите ваше мнимание на: https://discuss.appium.io/t/how-to-click-on-home-back-and-recent-button-in-android/3348

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на мой вопрос. В `env.rb` прописываем

```
$capy_driver = Capybara.current_session.driver
```

И используем в степе

```
$capy_driver.go_back
```

Но я так понял, можно и таким методом

```
$capy_driver.appium_driver.press_keycode 4
```